# How to pass a parameter to a block executed asynchronously in Swift?

Tags: swift, function, asynchronous, parameter-passing, dispatch-queue

In addition to [`function dispatch_async`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1453057-dispatch_async?language=objc), that submits a block for asynchronous execution, iOS provides another [`function dispatch_async_f`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452834-dispatch_async_f) to submit a function with a single parameter for asynchronous execution.
in Swift, I can call `dispatch_async` as `DispatchQueue.global().async {}`, but I did not find any way to call `dispatch_async_f`.
So, how do I pass a parameter to a block executed asynchronously?

Comment: You don't need that in Swift. Just `DispatchQueue.global().async { yourFunction(yourParameter) }`

Comment: Ahh! So simple! Thanks for your quick answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dispatch_async_f()` can be used in C code, which has no blocks or closures.

In Swift you simply pass a closure, and the closure calls the function:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    let theParameter = ...
    theFunction(theParameter)
}
```

The closure can also capture values when created:

```
let theParameter = ...
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    theFunction(theParameter)
}
```